# Using EuclideanDistance consecutively

Tags: graphics, geometry

[image: triangle]

To get the distance between point c and d, I tried using the following

`EuclideanDistance[c, d] /. %["Points"]`

Then I want to find the length of another line from the same scene, but I cannot use the above code twice.

```
EuclideanDistance[c, d] /. %["Points"]
EuclideanDistance[d, p] /. %["Points"]
```

What should I use then?

Comment: `%` represents the output of the last computation. You can not unse use again and again and hope to refer to the solution of points. Save whatever was in the computation in a symbol and the use that in the replacement rule `/.`

Comment: Or use `%%` in the second row. Or `%n` where `n` is the cell number. It's documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to extract properties from a geometric scene is to give it an name. Like so;

```
gs =
  RandomInstance[
    GeometricScene[
      {a, c, p, q, d},
      {Line[{a, c}], Line[{a, d, p}], Line[{c, d, q}],
       EuclideanDistance[a, d] == 3,
       EuclideanDistance[c, d] == 4,
       EuclideanDistance[a, c] == 5}],
    RandomSeeding -> 2]
```

[image: geom]

Then distances may be extracted and displayed with

```
Column[
 {EuclideanDistance[a, d] /. gs["Points"],
  EuclideanDistance[d, p] /. gs["Points"],
  EuclideanDistance[c, d] /. gs["Points"],
  EuclideanDistance[d, q] /. gs["Points"]}]
```

or

```
Column[
  {EuclideanDistance[a, d],
   EuclideanDistance[d, p],
   EuclideanDistance[c, d],
   EuclideanDistance[d, q]}
  /. gs["Points"]]
```

which is more concise and efficient. Both give the result

[image: result]